# Dismissing a ViewController shown as Popover segue from within another Popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

My storyboard is using a `UINavigationController`(VC0), I segue using a `UIPopover` to load a new `UIViewController` (VC1). From this new `UIViewController`, I am popping to a new `UIViewController` (VC2). When I attempt to close this newest popover, I am being quit back to the `UINavigationController`.

The code that I'm using in VC0 to show the VC1 as popover, VC1 to VC2 is the same code (different identifier though):

```objc
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"titlePopover" sender:self];
```

The code that I'm using in VC2 to dismiss the popover is:

```objc
UIViewController *vc = [self presentingViewController];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [[vc presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

What it does is dismisses VC2, shows VC1 for a split second, then dismisses VC1 and goes back to the VC0. I want to be able to dismiss VC2 only, so that I'm on VC1

Comment: You want dismiss just VC2 not VC1?

Comment: @NiravD, yes. Just dismiss VC2

Comment: Is below answer helps you?

Comment: @NiravD Yes, `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` worked in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you performing `sugue` modally, use code navigate back:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

If performing push `segue`, use code to navigate back:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` worked for me in my case. Thank you

Comment: happy to help :)