# How to have back button in order to go back to First ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I want to have button back in navigation controller in order to get back to my previous `viewcontroller`. You can look on images below to make clearly.

Please give me the ideas. I spent much to do it but can't do it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: your initial viewCont must embed with `navigationController` then create connection with another vc where in case of push segue you will get inbuild option to get back, look also http://stackoverflow.com/a/42672029/4003548.

Comment: When I do so, I will lost my second navigation controller

Comment: You can use poptoroot by navigationviewcontroller.

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

Add navigation controller to your home page

[image: storyboard image]

**RESULT**

[image: result image]

Comment: In my second page, it also has navigation controlller. if I do like that I will lost my second navigation controller.

Comment: No it will not be lost. Instead the navigation works perfectly fine. I will upload another image to clarify.

Comment: Good great, how can we implement brother?

Comment: I have shown it in image itself. Look closely the first image. And if you got your answer Please accept this. Thank you. If any problem, then happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can create custom back button and on click you have to put this code

```
@IBAction func customBack(_ sender: Any) {
   _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your storyboard and tap on navigationcontroller and select

```
'show navigation bar'
```

it will show your navigation bar.

But if you want to make a custom button then simply take a button from storyboard and  add this code in its action.

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to create a parent class in which you will create back button, this way you can re-use this code

1. create an Parent class

```
class ParentClass: UIViewController {

func addBackBtnWithImageName(string:String)-> Void
    {
let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
 button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: string), for: UIControlState.normal)
 button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(backbtnClick), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
  }

 func backbtnClick()  {
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

}
```

2. Your class where you want to add back button

```
class YourClass: ParentClass /*inheriting from parent class*/ {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            self.addBackBtnWithImageName(string: "Back")
    }
}
```

In any class where you want to add back button, just inherit from parent class and add this line in viewdidload:

```
self.addBackBtnWithImageName(string: "Back")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add UIbutton or UIbarButtonItem to your navigation bar. Then you need to bind the button to view controller. Follow the code..

```
@IBAction func backPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Solution for disappearing the Navigation Bar. Add this code..

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way in storyboard.

> Press CTRL key and hold. Then tap the button with Khmer Comedy title
>   and drag the mouse to your destination ViewController that displays
>   the details about Khmer Comedy. Then release CTRL and the mouse and
>   that's it.

Answer (score 0):

add navigation controller on main.storyboard
goto to Editor-> embed in -> navigation controller

this generate the button back for you